# drupal 7: display book module navigation horizontally

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7

I am using the book module navigation block to display links to book pages. I was wondering if it was possible to alter it so rather than the children links appearing below the parent, they would appear to the side. This is because I want a horizontal navigation:

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the navigation block with the [book-navigation.tpl.php template](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book-navigation.tpl.php/7). You have total control over the HTML within that block from that template. It basically allows links for next, previous and parent elements as well as the display of a list of links to any children. If you want to create a more complicated form of navigation (for instance: a javascript-powered slideshow with slides for every page at the current level of the book hierarchy) you'll have to resort to a custom view and find a way to [embed it](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) in the navigation template.